# SQL Server Stored Procedure store return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Helo,

My question is I have one Stored Procedure in SQL Server that returns counts of a field. I want to store the results of this Stored Procedure in a variable (scalar?) of a different stored procedure.

```
sp_My_Other_SP:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_My_Other_SP
@variable int OUTPUT -- The returned count
AS

BEGIN -- SP

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah"
EXEC(@SQL)

END -- SP
```

I currently do it like:

```
DECLARE @count int

EXEC sp_My_Other_SP @count OUTPUT
```

Then I use it like

```
IF (@count > 0)
BEGIN
...
END
```

However its returning the other Stored Procedure results as well as the main Stored Procedure results which is a problem in my .NET application.

```
-----------
NoColName
-----------
14

-----------
MyCol
-----------
abc
cde
efg
```

(Above is an attempted representation of the results sets returned)

I would like to know if there is a way to store the results of a Stored Procedure into a variable that doesn't also output it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you'll have to show us more code since your question isn't clear.

Comment: I agree.. show us the whole context.. the call to the "other" stored proc.

Comment: The problem is that the sproc returning the count includes more than that in its resultset, and this output is turning up in the 2nd sproc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can capture the results of the stored procedure into a temp table so it is not returned by the calling stored procedure.

```
create table #temp (id int, val varchar(100))
insert into #temp
exec sp_My_Other_SP @value, @value, @value, @count OUTPUT
```

Comment: I used this approach but rather than a hash table I used the TABLE scalar type like:

DECLARE @temp_tbl TABLE( value int )

INSERT INTO @temp_tbl EXEC sp_My_SP
   
SET @count = (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM @temp_tbl)

Comment: This is of course less efficient since you're selecting data you don't care about.  You'd be better off adding a new parameter to sp_My_Other_SP that controls whether or not the result set is returned if you're just looking for a count.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, I care about the count as I will always use it and it is vital to the rest of the SP.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easiest way to fix this is to recode the stored proc so that the select statement that returns the 'other' result set you don't want in this case is conditionally extecuted, only when you are NOT asking for the count

Add another parameter called @GetCount

```
@GetCount TinyInt Defualt = 0 // or
@GetCount Bit Default = 0
```

Then 
   instead of just

```
Select ...
```

write

```
   If @GetCount = 1
     Select ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing

```
SET @SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah" 
EXEC(@SQL)
```

to

```
SELECT @variable = COUNT(*) FROM blah" 
-- don't do EXEC(@SQL)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
THE FIRST PROCEDURE:
CREATE PROC DD43
@ID INT OUTPUT AS
(SELECT @ID=COUNT(*) FROM CS2)

SECOND PROCEDURE:

 CREATE PROC DD45 AS
 DECLARE @COUNT INT
 DECLARE @COUN INT
 EXEC DD43 @COUN OUT --CALLING THE FIRST PROCEDURE
 SET @COUNT= (SELECT @COUN)
 SELECT @COUNT

 EXEC DD45
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.